# What does "vergeben" relationship status mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I see that some people in German-speaking chats have relationship status (Beziehungsstatus) ***vergeben***.

What does it mean? Does it mean that a person ***is forgiven***?
If so, what does it mean anyway?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

***Vergeben*** in relationship status means that those people currently are in a relation already.

Similar to the English, *taken*.

It has nothing to do with the English *forgiving*, but simply means these are already *committed* into an existing relationship.

In German ***vergeben*** is used for several things depending on context, like

- > Der Platz ist bereits *vergeben*
  >
  > > That seat is already *occupied* (*taken*)
- > Wir *vergeben* ihm, da er es nicht besser wusste
  >
  > > We *forgive* him, since he didn't know better

Comment: Old English *forgiefan* has also the meaning *to give in marriage*. See .e.g https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343990/etymology-of-word-forgive

Comment: A good rule of thumb in German: the *ver-* prefix can frequently be taken to mean "to do to the greatest extent possible -- until it can no longer be done".  In this manner, *vergeben* could be interpreted as "to be given completely".  It's not a far stretch to see how that translates to "taken".

Answer (score 14):

*Geben* translates to "give", but translating *vergeben* to "forgiven" is  a false friend **in this context** (but possible in other contexts).

> [vergeben:](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vergeben)
>   Bedeutungen
>
> etw. (an jmdn.) weggeben, verteilen
>   umgangssprachlich: zwei Töchter der Familie waren schon vergeben (= verheiratet, verlobt)
>   –– colloquially: two daughters of the family were already taken (= married, engaged)

As a figure of speech it's still very similar to see this connection:
Have you seen a marriage ceremony? The father [*gives away*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch-deutsch/give-away) the bride.

> “given away” could be Past Participle
>   give away  verb
>   vergeben v
>   On the occasion of its anniversary, the company gave away gift vouchers.
>   –– Zum Anlass ihres Jubiläums vergab die Firma Geschenkgutscheine.
>   <sub>[Linguee Dictionary: given away](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/given+away.html)</sub>

So, depending on perspective *vergeben* could be read as "already taken" or "already given away".

---

The practical explanation above is rooted in the theoretical explanation provided by linguistics when looking into the etymologies:

*Geben* and *give* are as much cognates as *vergeben* and *forgiven*:

> German cognate | Meaning of German cognate | English cognate  | Proto-Germanic root
>   geben, gab, (ge)geben | to give | give, gave, given | *gebaną
>   <sup>[WP: Loanwords from Old Norse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English)</sup>
>
> **forgive (v.)**
>
> Old English *forgiefan* "give, grant, allow; remit (a debt), pardon (an offense)," also "give up" and ***"give in marriage"*** (past tense forgeaf, past participle forgifen); from **for-**, here probably "completely," + giefan "to give" (from PIE root ***ghabh-** "to give or receive").
>
> The sense of "to give up desire or power to punish" (late Old English) is from use of such a compound as a Germanic loan-translation of Vulgar Latin *perdonare (Old Saxon fargeban, Dutch vergeven, German vergeben "to forgive," Gothic fragiban "to grant;" and see **pardon** (n.)). Related: Forgave; forgiven; forgiving.
>   <sup>[Etymology of *forgive*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forgive)</sup>
>
> **vergeben** Vb. ‘***weggeben***, austeilen, ***verschenken***, verzeihen’, meist reflexiv ‘seinem Ansehen schaden’, nur reflexiv ‘sich beim Austeilen (der Spielkarten) irren, falsch geben’, ahd. firgeban ‘vergeben, schenken, einräumen’ (8. Jh.), mhd. vergeben;
>   <sup>DWDS: [geben/Etymologie](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vergeben)</sup>

That means that both words share the exact same root but the English word *forgiven* has lost a part of the original meaning ("to give away"/"to be given away") while the German word *vergeben* retained that meaning and expanded it to encompass not only married people (specifically women) but now means any sex and gender committed in a relationship.

Answer (score 6):

While πάντα ῥεῖ has already answered the question, let me explain why your assumption wasn't a bad one.

> Does it mean that a person is forgiven?

In German-like languages, it could've been literally translated like that and still work. However, English is not a German-like language. In Dutch, however and for example, it would've worked. "Vergeben" would translate to "vergeven", which either means "forgiven" or "already occupied/taken/given away", but also "awarded", "handed out" or "assigned". It can be translated one-on-one regardless of context (although it looks archaic in some of those cases).

It's one of those words with multiple meanings which can translate directly to another language with the same meanings or a language where the meanings are split up. There's probably a term for it.

The vocabulary and grammatical similarity of German to English are simply too low to reliably make literal translations like that.

Comment: In German (and the answer was about a status in German), "vergeben" can very well mean "forgiven", so his assumption was not bad at all and why he could very well make such an assumption. He simply didn't know the other meaning, i.e. "taken". And "vergeven" is very very seldom used in Dutch when it is supposed to have the meaning of "weggegeven", or "verkeerd gegeven".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Hence the mention of being archaic.

Comment: If I should simply remove the answer, feel free to let me know.

Comment: @Mast: it doesn't make a lot of sense. It doesn't improve the other answer and mainly discusses Dutch, which is quite beside the point. I would remove it, if it were mine.

Comment: It is an interesting observation that you could further elaborate with some etymology. Both, [*to forgive*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forgive), and [*vergeben*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vergeben) share the same roots in that *to give away a seat* and *to give away pardon* are basically the same. Only the meaning *to award, to give away* is lost in English today (but not in Dutch or German).

Comment: Indeed, while arguing that English is not German-like, what this post actually does is dig up the evidence to back up the historical fact that it actually is very German in origin.  Many things like this that are assumed different are really just situations where one branch of the similarity has fallen out of everyday usage - but is still immediately understood when encountered in historical context.  It's clear what "given" means as a relationship status, it's more the lack of awareness that "forgiven" as "pardon" is an abstraction from this root which is to blame for the confusion.

Comment: And on that note, hearing either language spoken poorly but deliberately by a native speaker of a third can be quite informative - the mental search for what the oddly used words were *intended* to mean can be fairly comparable to weighing the differences in modern usage between the two.

Comment: There is no such thing as "German-like language". English is Germanic language and this is as far as it gets. Some languages share some features with German and some do not; some share some other features. It's wrong to think that there are some mythical "German-like languages" out there. They are all proper languages on their own. Unless you want to define yourself what  exactly "German-like languages" means and use that definition for the purpose of your answer.

Comment: Believe it or not, Dutch is the closest living relative of English, linguistically. Both are Germanic languages, as @AndrewSavinykh already noted. But words do change meaning over time, acquire new meanings and lose those they had. However close E. and Du. are linguistically, they have diverged between at least 1600 (*terminus ante quem* High Germanic consonant shift happened but did not affect them both) and, more certainly, 1100 (first written Old English) years ago. This is too much time to expect any word to preserve a stable meaning (although many words indeed do).

Comment: @ChrisStratton, you should write that as an answer!

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is about Dutch, while the exact same answer could have been written about German! (If anything, focusing on Dutch makes it more confusing, since the Dutch word _vergeven_ also means _vergiften_.)

Answer (score 0):

"Vergeben" literally means something like "given up."

In a "dating" context, the English expression is "taken." That is, when you have been "taken" by someone, you have "given up" yourself to that person.

In the more usual context, if you have "given up" your grudge at someone's causing you offense, you have "forgiven" them.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a prefix issue: [DWDS: ver-](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ver-) lists some possible modifications of meanings of the successive verb, which are surprisingly many and diverse.

> [combinations with other word types omitted ...]
> 4. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass eine Sache durch etw. (ein Tun) beseitigt, verbraucht wird, nicht mehr besteht
> 5. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass eine Person mit etw. ihre Zeit verbringt
> 6. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass eine Person etw. falsch, verkehrt macht
> 7. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass eine Sache durch etw. beeinträchtigt wird
> 8. hat in Bildungen mit Verben die gleiche Bedeutung wie diese

Your *vergeben* example falls into category 4: given/promised to somebody else, so no longer available. One of the most frequent other members of this meaning category is probably *verkaufen* (sell). If something is *verkauft* (sold), somebody else bought it already, so it is no longer available either.

The full dictionary entry [dwds: vergeben](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vergeben) shows under its subsection 5, that other meanings of vergeben exist as well. Making an error when dealing playing cards is also called *vergeben* corresponding to upper category 6.